# How to create more dimensions for data mining?

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data-cleaning, weka

I want to analyze product sales data with [WEKA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_(machine_learning)). My data have attributes: sell quantity and sales price. I want to add more attributes, such as mean and standard deviation.

What formula I should use to create more dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is called [feature engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_engineering). Expansion of dataset attributes via attribute transformations is called basis function expansion. These are often nonlinear functions of the original attributes. Popular nonlinear functions are [polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial).